# What is the etiquette about including information that somebody else provided?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

A while ago, I had a strange encounter on music.SO. I had posted an answer, then person A added a few comments with additional information. I edited my answer to add this information, *clearly crediting person A for this*. Interestingly, person A also added an *answer* of his own, not including the information he had given in these commends. Person B then came in the picture and edited both answers: he removed the information from my answer and added it to person A's answer, saying that it's not right for me to gain reputation for information that does not come from me.

It happened a while ago, but I'd still like to ask: what is the correct way to deal with these things? Was person B right to do what he did? Was I in the right when adding information to my answer even though I did not directly find it myself? What is the etiquette about things like this?

Comment: I'd say removing information from an answer like that actively goes against the philosophy of SE. You edit posts to *improve* them, not to make them worse.

Answer (score 9):

The whole *point* of commenting on an answer with additional information is because you want the author of that post to edit their answer to incorporate the information in your comment.  The *goal* of a comment is to improve the post it is commenting on.  Given that, the edit you made was entirely appropriate.

That user is also entirely within their rights to post another answer.  It probably would have made sense for them to incorporate the information they felt your answer should have included; it's not really *wrong* for them not to, just unusual.

It's entirely inappropriate for someone to come in an remove the information from your answer.

As for editing it into the other user's answer, that's an unusual case.  I wouldn't do it myself, but I'm not sure that I'd consider it *wrong* to do so (since it's their own content after all, so it's not like you're putting words in their mouth or anything).

Answer (score 3):

Servy's answer is good, and I upvoted it. Here are some additional thoughts I had:

**When in doubt, I suggest you optimize for two things:**

- Creating the best, most complete answers possible, with as little answer fragmentation as is reasonable...
- Giving fair, reasonable credit wherever someone else contributed in any way (on site or off) to a good answer.

In your case, it's a no-brainer to me:  A comment with more info is *outright inviting* you to add the info to your answer, and the appropriate attribution there is a hat tip crediting the user who suggested it.

But I'd go one farther, and suggest it's okay in some cases to incorporate info *from other answers* into yours in some circumstances. Personally, I bucket like this to see when pulling in info from another answer is in the best interest of the community:

**Pick one answer or the other? Don't combine.** If your answer is one solution, but another good answer is a totally different (but good) approach, I'd advise *against* pulling theirs in, but might edit a reference to theirs into yours. ("If you need a solution that requires no use of lizards, consider @Englebert's alternate method, which I upvoted.")

**Another answer is additive to your solution - consider incorporating, with credit, and an upvote.** This applies best when someone's answer is most useful *in combination with yours*.  This applies to answers like,

> "YOURNAME's 9 steps are dead on, but if none work, this 10th one
>   will often solve it."

or

> As YOURNAME pointed out, you can YOUR SOLUTION unless the cat is already on fire, in which case, you'll be better off running with THEIR SOLUTION.

In both cases, the other answer is a legitimate answer, not a comment, but both answers are *much* more useful together than separated, and way more people will benefit in the long run if they're combined.  Personally, when it's one of those, I usually add the info, but with credit and a suggestion in my answer that readers upvote the one I incorporated.

It's a tricky balance. More readers are helped when info is consolidated, but the system depends on individuals feeling like they'll be recognized for their contributions.

Comment: No use of lizards? That's speciesist! And Bill probably isn't going to be happy with you... :-P